# Load image from Bundle I get a nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

When I try to get a UIImage from my project using NSBundle I get a nil value. 
I have the image into `.xcassests`

This is my code to load image from bundle.

```
- (UIImage *)imageRating:(NSString *)imageName
{
  return [UIImage imageNamed:imageName inBundle:[MyClass bundle] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
}
```

And this is the Bundle Method.

```
+ (NSBundle *)bundle
 {
    return [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
 }
```

Any idea why I get a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the resource path is wrong.

Your image is placed in `.xcassests` and is finally packaged in the `.app` file, which is commonly used in `main bundle`.

If your project structure contains a `framework`, just if you get the current bundle in the `framwork`, then the path is not the resource under the main bundle, but the bundle resource of the `framwork`.

Because I don't know your project structure, the next step is to know the path to print the bundle and compare it with the `main bundle` path.

```
- (UIImage *)imageRating:(NSString *)imageName
{
  NSBundle *bundle = [MyClass bundle];
  NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSLog(@"bundle: %@\n main bundle: %@",imageBundle);
  return [UIImage imageNamed:imageName inBundle:[MyClass bundle] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
}
```

If the paths are different, there are two ways.

1. Put resources in the form of bundles in `famework`
2. Change `[MyClass bundle]` to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`